# Proof $1 \geq \prod_{k=m}^n\left\{ 1-\frac{\sin^2 \frac{x}{2n-1}}{\sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2n-1}} \right\}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, infinite-product

I am trying to proof the following equation:

$$\sin (x)= x\prod_{i=1}^\infty \left( 1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2} \right).$$

I got a proof but there is one point that I do not understand.

There is one step during the proof presented the following equation

$$
1 \geq \prod_{k=m}^n\left\{ 1-\frac{\sin^2 \frac{x}{2n-1}}{\sin^2 \frac{k\pi}{2n-1}} \right\}
$$

I am kind of confusing and do not know how to prove it. If anyone can help me and prove it in detail. Thanks!

Comment: All their zeroes match.....

Comment: You might want to look up Euler's Original proof for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. That will give you some ideas.

Comment: @ReverseFlow Thank you mate, but I searched and couldn't find the proof you mentioned. Would you be so kind to be more specific??

Comment: @user5713492 thanks, updated~~

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro

Comment: A proof of the Weierstrass product for the sine function over the real line can be found at page 33 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view). The key idea is to exploit the factorization of Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind and convexity inequalities for the sine function.